# Change texture of a SKNode once it is placed?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, sknode

Note: I have looked at previous SO questions on this subject. I have tried the methods suggested to no avail. The suggestion to change the texture of the node is already implemented, and as I have a "texture" variable for the SKNode I want to change, I see no reason to convert to a SKSpriteNode (as was suggested in another post)

In my game I need to change the textures of cities when they are captured. Capturing does work, but the texture change does not.

Here is the code I wrote to change the texture of the city:

```
if attackedCity?.team == "Red"{
            attackedCity?.texture = textureRedCity
            print("City now Red")
        } else if attackedCity?.team == "Blue"{
            attackedCity?.texture = textureBlueCity
            print("City now Blue")
        }
```

The cities do produce units of the team that captured them, but the texture of the cities does not change. E.g. it looks like a blue city is producing red units.

The class "City" (which attackedCity is just a part of, it is a tester to select a city from an array of cities) is a subclass of "Improvement" which is itself an 'SKNode'.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```swift
let newTexture = SKTexture()
let action = SKAction.setTexture(newTexture)
spriteNode.run(action)
```

Answer (score -1):

Define your textures ahead of time:

```
let redTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "redTexture")
let blueTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "blueTexture")
```

Then animate the texture change when needed:

```
let changeTexture = SKAction.animate(with: [redTexture], timePerFrame: 0.25, resize: true, restore: false)
attackCity.run(changeTexture)
```

Comment: The textures are defined elsewhere. But is there no permanent way to change the texture without animation? As I want to keep the texture to the texture I changed it too, which I assume would work with animation?

Comment: with restore:false, the new texture will stay.

Comment: Found an alternate way to fix it (as I do not know how to make the SKAction affect the city that was attacked)

Comment: You can call it directly on the object using `.run` or .`sequence`. See editied answer

Comment: Should I test it out? As I already found an alternate solution that works.

Comment: It's up to you, just wanted to provide clarification. Also, I don't know what your final solution was...

Comment: See the answer involving making an entirely new city.

Comment: That seems like a more expensive option.

Answer (score -1):

Create a newCity with the same stats as the old one.

E.g.

```
let RedCity = City(texture: textureRedCity, tag: (attackedCity?.tag)!, health: 1, production: 1, workDone: 0)
RedCity.position = (attackedCity?.position)!
RedCity.team = "Red"
improvementsLayer.addChild(RedCity)
cityList[attackedListPos] = RedCity
```

I assume this works as the cities are SKNodes with SKSpriteNodes on top of them that are set to be a texture when loaded, so they are unchangeable. So the fix is to reload the SKSpriteNodes which can be accomplished by deleting the old city and replacing it with a new one with the same tag and position in the array of cities